# What to do about 'discard' in Purescript do-notation?

Tags: purescript, do-notation

Having a problem with some of the examples in the Learn Purescript by Example book. Specifically this code from section 9.3:

```
main :: Eff (canvas :: CANVAS) Unit
main = void $ unsafePartial do
  Just canvas <- getCanvasElementById "canvas"
  ctx <- getContext2D canvas

  setFillStyle "#0000FF" ctx -- this's line 16 referred to in the error message

  fillPath ctx $ rect ctx
    { x: 250.0
    , y: 250.0
    , w: 100.0
    , h: 100.0
    }
```

gives the following error:

> in module Example.Rectangle
>   at src\Example\Rectangle.purs line 16, column 3 - line 16, column 29
>
> A result of type
>
> Context2D
>
> was implicitly discarded in a do notation block.
>    You can use _ <- ... to explicitly discard the result.
>
> while applying a function discard
>    of type Discard t0 => Bind t1 => t1 t0 -> (t0 -> t1 t2) -> t1 t2
>    to argument (setFillStyle "#0000FF") ctx
>   while inferring the type of discard ((setFillStyle "#0000FF") ctx)
>   in value declaration main
>
> where t0 is an unknown type
>        t2 is an unknown type
>        t1 is an unknown type
>
> See https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/NoInstanceFound.md for more information,

The suggested error doesn't help and I can't work out what "discard" acctualy does. I also noticed a similar problem with, for example, the "simulate" function from section 8.17. If I try the suggestion of assigning using "_ <- " more random seeming errors crop up.

(This is using PSCi 0.11.5)

Comment: Please, share your code, not link to book. This don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is no more allowed to implicitly discard a value in a do block.

You can:
- ignore the value explicitly: _ <- setFillStyle....
- or if the return value is Unit (e.g. Eff fx Unit) you can simply import "discard" from "Prelude"

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `void $ setFilleStyle...` where `void` comes from prelude.

Comment: Thank you, both of those solutions work, tho it does get a bit verbose